# Integral type class comparisons

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Currently brushing up on my Haskell by doing Codewars. I have made the following code,

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)

calc :: String -> Int
calc s = sum $ map (\i -> (digitToInt i)^n) s
        where n = length s

narcissistic :: Integral n => n -> Bool
narcissistic n = calc s == n
                where s = show n
```

Which produces,

```
Couldn't match expected type 'Int' with actual type 'n'
      'n' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          narcissistic :: forall n. Integral n => n -> Bool
```

To my knowledge this is caused by the fact that the *narcissistic* function taking an input *n* which is within the Integral type class (Int or Integer). However the *calc* function produces an Int. Thus I cannot compare the result of *calc* and the *n*.

My question is thus, what would be the ideal way to work with these type classes, and how would I be able to implement a function such as *calc* which would possibly work with the Integral class type (unable to do so because of the *digitToInt*?).

Answer (score 6):

`calc` specifically returns an `Int`, which means `==` also expects an `Int`, but you are only providing an `Integral n => n` value. Sure, `narcissistic` *could* be called with an `Int`, but it could just as well be called with an `Integer` or some other type with an `Integral` instance.

To make the comparison, you need a common type. You can use `toInteger :: Integral a => a -> Integer` on *both* `calc s` and `n` to get `Integer` values that can be compared directly.

```
narcissistic :: (Show n, Integral n) => n -> Bool
narcissistic n = toInteger (calc s) == toInteger n
     where s = show n
```

Note that `Integral` does not imply `Show`; you need to add that to the constraints as well.

However... you can't know that the number `calc` computes from the `String` input will fit in an `Int`; you should return an `Integer` in the first place, then use `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b` to turn `n` into an `Integer`.

```
calc :: String -> Integer
calc s = sum $ map (\i -> (fromIntegral (digitToInt i))^n) s
        where n = length s

narcissistic :: Integral n => n -> Bool
narcissistic n = calc s == fromIntegral n
                where s = show n
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would I be able to implement a function such as `calc` which would possibly work with the Integral class type (unable to do so because of the `digitToInt`?).

You can use [`fromIntegral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to [convert that `Int` to any `Integral`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers) (or even more generically, any `Num`, but we don't need that here):

```
calc :: Integral i => String -> i
calc s = sum $ map (\i -> (fromIntegral $ digitToInt i)^n) s
        where n = length s
```